# Linux Redhat Update to Java 7

Tags: java, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm trying to update to java 7, via command line but having no luck, can someone help me out please? I've done some searching, but haven't come up with anything that works so far.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried http://java.com/en/download/help/linux_install.xml

Your going to want the RPM package if your on redhat
http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=64144